# Best Practice of High Availability For MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, galera, maxscale

I'm preparing to run a MariaDB Cluster with High Availability and I'm looking for the best practices.

Years back, I used to run MariaDB in master-master mode, and there was a big issue. Whenever any of the nodes (two nodes in total) was disconnected and reconnected for a second, the whole database was inaccessible until the sync process was completed.

I did search a lot and there are multiple suggestions, which not sure which one is the best and simple solution to go for.

1. using maxscale as proxy
2. using master-slave mode
3. using master-master mode

I haven't worked with MaxScale, and I would be thankful if someone guides me if this is the best solution to go for a database with high I/O, also I know that I need to have another MaxScale + HAProxy setup to cover MaxScale failures.

The second item is not a proper solution, since if the master DB fails I need to go over some manual processes to make it as master.

The third item, could be used with Galera, but as I searched I saw many people complaining about the sync issues which I had before.

I would be thankful if someone can guide me with at least 2-3 years of experience in such a cluster.

Comment: Depending on your application, you might not need a HAProxy in front of MaxScale if the database connector you use supports multiple endpoints. An alternative would be to use DNS level load balancing to spread the requests to both MaxScale instances. MaxScale can manage the replication of a master-slave cluster for using the `auto_failover` option in the `mariadbmon` module, this takes care of the second option and avoids the usual problems you run into with multi-master setups.

Comment: Thanks for your given guide. now I know what to do with two MaxScale services without HAProxy.  but what about MaxScale itself. is it reliable for the enterprise environemnt? and my second question, if there is a problem in the network layer and for any reason, I lose any of the DB nodes, after rejoining it to the cluster again, am  I  going to face any issue likewise i used to have? final question is, why to deploy master-slave mode.

Comment: 3 nodes with Galera seems like what you need.  Are you familiar with [`wsrep_sync_wait`](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/galera#critical_reads) ?  If you have heard of other "sync issues"; do you have any links to such complaints?

Comment: And, as for single-Primary vs multi-Primary, that may boil down to which one involves fewer changes in your app.

Comment: @RickJames thanks Rick, but would you please explain more about, what do you exactly mean by saying  "that may boil down to which one involves fewer changes in your app".

Comment: @ZarehKasparian - If the app writes to all Galera nodes, then there _may_ be a "Critical read" issue -- where something posted on one node is not yet on another node if you read from it "too fast".  It is a classic problem in Primary-Replica split: one cannot blindly route _every_ Select to the Replica(s).  (See my link.)

Comment: If there may be a critical read, but its not known if or what the timeframe is, [WSREP_LAST_WRITTEN_GTID](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/wsrep_last_written_gtid/), to save the read point required (maybe even to a user cookie or session info), and when a critical read happens `SELECT `[WSREP_SYNC_WAIT_UPTO_GTID](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/wsrep_sync_wait_upto_gtid/).